# How to verify that column data_type are the same as foreign key data_type in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

Is there a way to check if all foreign key columns data_type are the same as the column they point to?

This code is valid and works until a user have an ID bigger than what int4 can handle.

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;
CREATE TABLE test.users (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    name varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE test.othertable (
    blabla varchar NULL,
    userid int4 NULL
);
ALTER TABLE test.othertable ADD CONSTRAINT newtable_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES test.users(id);
```

Comment: If the data types were incompatible, the constraint wouldn't be enforceable. This is checked if the constraint is defined. Incompatible types will cause an error.

Comment: You are correct. It is a semantic error, though. The FK works *until* it tries to refer to a bigint value that doesn't fit into an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An (incomplete) version, using the bare pg_catalogs instead of the information_schema wrapper:

---

```
SELECT version();

DROP SCHEMA test CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA test;
SET search_path = test;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial NOT NULL CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY
    , name varchar NULL
);
CREATE TABLE othertable (
    blabla varchar NULL
    , userid int4 NULL CONSTRAINT bad_fk REFERENCES users(id)
    , goodid bigint NULL CONSTRAINT good_fk REFERENCES users(id)
);

PREPARE insert_two(bigint, text, text) AS
WITH one AS (
        INSERT INTO users (id, name)
        VALUES ( $1, $2)
        RETURNING id
        )
INSERT INTO othertable (userid, goodid, blabla)
SELECT id, id, $3
FROM one
        ;

EXECUTE insert_two(1, 'one', 'bla1' );
EXECUTE insert_two(2, 'two', 'bla2' );
EXECUTE insert_two(10000000000::bigint, 'toobig', 'bigbla' );

SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM othertable;

SET search_path = pg_catalog;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH cat AS (   -- Class Attribute Type
        SELECT cl.oid AS coid, cl.relname
        , at.attnum AS cnum, at.attname
        , ty.oid AS toid, ty.typname
        FROM pg_class cl
        JOIN pg_attribute at ON at.attrelid = cl.oid AND at.attnum > 0 -- suppres system columns
        JOIN pg_type ty ON ty.oid = at.atttypid
        )
SELECT ns.nspname
        , co.*
        , source.relname AS source_table, source.attname AS source_column, source.typname AS source_type
        , target.relname AS target_table, target.attname AS target_column, target.typname AS target_type
FROM pg_constraint co
JOIN pg_namespace ns ON co.connamespace = ns.oid
        -- NOTE: this only covers single-column FKs
JOIN cat source ON source.coid = co.conrelid AND co.conkey[1] = source.cnum
JOIN cat target ON target.coid = co.confrelid AND co.confkey[1] = target.cnum
WHERE 1=1
AND co.contype = 'f'
AND ns.nspname = 'test'
  -- commented out the line below, to show the differences between "good" and "bad" FK constraints. 
-- AND source.toid <> target.toid
        ;
```

---

Rsults (look at the operators, it is a feature, not a bug!)

---

```
                                                version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.6 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0, 32-bit
(1 row)

NOTICE:  drop cascades to 2 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to table test.users
drop cascades to table test.othertable
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
PREPARE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  integer out of range
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | one
  2 | two
(2 rows)

 blabla | userid | goodid 
--------+--------+--------
 bla1   |      1 |      1
 bla2   |      2 |      2
(2 rows)

SET
 nspname | conname | connamespace | contype | condeferrable | condeferred | convalidated | conrelid | contypid | conindid | conparentid | confrelid | confupdtype | confdeltype | confmatchtype | conislocal | coninhcount | connoinherit | conkey | confkey | conpfeqop | conppeqop | conffeqop | conexclop | conbin | consrc | source_table | source_column | source_type | target_table | target_column | target_type 
---------+---------+--------------+---------+---------------+-------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------
 test    | good_fk |       211305 | f       | f             | f           | t            |   211317 |        0 |   211315 |           0 |    211308 | a           | a           | s             | t          |           0 | t            | {3}    | {1}     | {410}     | {410}     | {410}     |           |        |        | othertable   | goodid        | int8        | users        | id            | int8
 test    | bad_fk  |       211305 | f       | f             | f           | t            |   211317 |        0 |   211315 |           0 |    211308 | a           | a           | s             | t          |           0 | t            | {2}    | {1}     | {416}     | {410}     | {96}      |           |        |        | othertable   | userid        | int4        | users        | id            | int8
(2 rows)
```

Comment: So finally you did this hard work ! :-) Your version is way more efficient, but the initial question was "a query for the foreign key whose types that does not match". That's why I edited your question prior to accept it.

Comment: I intentionally commented out the `AND source.toid <> target.toid` line, just to show the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I made this query that check this :

```
select
    tc.table_schema, 
    tc.constraint_name, 
    tc.table_name, 
    kcu.column_name, 
    ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name,
    sc.data_type  AS data_type,
    dc.data_type AS foreign_data_type
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
  ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
  AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
JOIN information_schema.columns sc ON sc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema and sc.table_name = kcu.table_name and sc.column_name = kcu.column_name
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
  ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
  AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
JOIN information_schema.columns dc ON dc.table_schema = ccu.table_schema and dc.table_name = ccu.table_name and dc.column_name = ccu.column_name
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
and  sc.data_type <> dc.data_type;
```

It is quite slow, any tips for optimisation is welcome.

Comment: information_schema is a set of views built on pg_catalogs. You could rewrite it using the actual pg_catalogs tables. That will be a lot of work.